# Push Async is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In **App.xaml.cs** i have following code:

```cs
MainPage = new LoginPage();  //LoginPage is ContentPage
```

When user click a `Button` on that page there is call to **MasterDetailPage** which is of `MasterDetailPage` type. This will be my real main page from where users will navigate to other pages. I treat it as central place for my application with `navigation bar`.

```cs
Application.Current.MainPage = new MasterDetailPage();
```

being in **MasterDetailPage** in `ctor` i set default page which open:

```cs
Detail = new NavigationPage(new ClientsPage());
```

Now, from here i have a `Button` to navigate to another `ContentPage` so when i click a `Button` this line is executed:

```cs
await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ClientModifyPage(_selectedClient));
```

Nevertheless i am getting following error:

> PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage

What's wrong?

Comment: MainPage is a MD Page, not a N. Page.

Comment: @SushiHangover not sure whether understood you correctly but i change my line to:  Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterDetailPage()); but then after that change i see duplicated navigation at the top, look: https://drive.google.com/open?id=114PcUByMl3SuhP_MbIih9eAr3rJMnQJh

Answer (score 2):

> await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ClientModifyPage(_selectedClient));

As **SushiHangover** said , it will be an expected result because **Application.Current.MainPage** is a MasterDetailPage , which is not in a NavigationPage .

You should call the method `PushAsync` in the detail page .

```
 await((MasterDetailPage)App.Current.MainPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new ClientModifyPage(_selectedClient));
```

Comment: before your answer i solved that doing as follows i added new Navigation as follows: Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterDetailPage()); and then i added this line: NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); once after  Detail = new NavigationPage(new ClientsPage()); now it works, what you think? and this line stay as it was before:     await _pageService.PushAsync(new ClientModifyPage(_selectedClient));

Comment: It is not  the best solution, you could try my answer (don't need to set the MasterDetailPage as NavigationPage) .

Comment: i did what you said but i get and exactly same error as before: System.InvalidOperationException: 'PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.'

Comment: Could you share a sample so that I can test it on my side

Comment: would be hard to extract ;/ its on the line you pasted. I can stay with hiding masterdetail navigation bar, unless you say something else to test

Comment: Where did you call the PushAsync, in ClientsPage ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206178/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-arie).

Answer (score 2):

place below the line in app.cs page

`MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());`

instead of

`MainPage = new LoginPage();`

And no need to use NavigationPage in other pages.NavigationPage should be used when we are redirecting the page first time in our application.
Here MainPage is the root page. We have to assign a page(LoginPage) to MainPage by using NavigationPage.